# How to invoke an action in UIViewController depending on a boolean in UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a class called DraggableViewBackground which is an UIView (representing swipe cards for questions).

However since this is an UIView, I cannot invoke a segue since it is a UIView and not an UIViewController. I assume it has something to do with delegate but I could not figure out how and if that's the right way to do that as I'm new to Swift.

EDIT: Im using the following Github project for the swipe cards: https://github.com/reterVision/TinderSwipeCardsSwift

How can I achieve a segue out of the corresponding UIViewController?

Here is the UIView class:

```
import Foundation
 import UIKit

class DraggableViewBackground: UIView, DraggableViewDelegate {
var exampleCardLabels: [String]!
var allCards: [DraggableView]!

let MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 2
let CARD_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 386
let CARD_WIDTH: CGFloat = 290

var cardsLoadedIndex: Int!
var loadedCards: [DraggableView]!
var menuButton: UIButton!
var messageButton: UIButton!
var checkButton: UIButton!
var xButton: UIButton!
var moveForwardButton: UIButton!
var actionCounter = 0

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.setupView()
    exampleCardLabels = ["Swipe right for YES", "Swipe left for NO","Study in the countryside?","Do you want to study in a city?"]
    allCards = []
    loadedCards = []
    cardsLoadedIndex = 0
    self.loadCards()
}

func setupView() -> Void {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.16, green: 0.21, blue: 0.34, alpha: 1)
//     UIColor colorWithRed:40.0f/255.0f green:54.0f/255.0f blue:89.0f/255.0f alpha:1
    xButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width -   CARD_WIDTH)/2 - 30, self.frame.size.height/2 + CARD_HEIGHT/2 + 10, 125, 125))

 //set button Image for No button
    xButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "swipe-left"), forState:   UIControlState.Normal)
    xButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DraggableViewBackground.swipeLeft), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    checkButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2 + CARD_WIDTH/2 - 85, self.frame.size.height/2 + CARD_HEIGHT/2 + 10, 125, 125))

 //set button Image for Check button
    checkButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "swipe-right"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    checkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DraggableViewBackground.swipeRight), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    moveForwardButton = UIButton()
    moveForwardButton.frame =  CGRectMake(160, 240, 35, 10);

    moveForwardButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    moveForwardButton.setTitle("Click here to proceed", forState: .Normal)
    moveForwardButton.center = self.center
    moveForwardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DraggableViewBackground.moveToNextScreen), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.addSubview(xButton)
    self.addSubview(checkButton)
  // self.addSubview(moveForwardButton)
}

func createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> DraggableView {
    let draggableView = DraggableView(frame: CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - CARD_WIDTH)/2, (self.frame.size.height - CARD_HEIGHT)/2, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT))
    draggableView.information.text = exampleCardLabels[index]
    draggableView.delegate = self
    return draggableView
}

//create all cards and all example cards into loaded cards
func loadCards() -> Void {
    if exampleCardLabels.count > 0 {
        let numLoadedCardsCap = exampleCardLabels.count > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE ? MAX_BUFFER_SIZE : exampleCardLabels.count
        for i in 0 ..< exampleCardLabels.count {
            let newCard: DraggableView = self.createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex(i)
            allCards.append(newCard)
            if i < numLoadedCardsCap {
                loadedCards.append(newCard)
            }
        }

        for i in 0 ..< loadedCards.count {
            if i > 0 {
                self.insertSubview(loadedCards[i], belowSubview: loadedCards[i - 1])
            } else {
                self.addSubview(loadedCards[i])
            }
            cardsLoadedIndex = cardsLoadedIndex + 1
        }
    } else {

        print("no more cards left, move to next screen")
    }
}

func cardSwipedLeft(card: UIView) -> Void {
    self.actionCounter = self.actionCounter + 1
    print("card has been swiped left")
    print("size of loaded card")
    print(actionCounter)
   //HERE THE SEGUE SHOULD BE INVOKED      

    if(actionCounter == 4) {
        print("invoke segue to next screen")
    }

    loadedCards.removeAtIndex(0)

    if cardsLoadedIndex < allCards.count {
        loadedCards.append(allCards[cardsLoadedIndex])
        cardsLoadedIndex = cardsLoadedIndex + 1
        self.insertSubview(loadedCards[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1], belowSubview: loadedCards[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 2])
    }
}

func cardSwipedRight(card: UIView) -> Void {

    print("card has been swiped right")

    self.actionCounter = self.actionCounter + 1
    print("card has been swiped left")
    print("size of loaded card")
    print(actionCounter)

 //HERE THE SEGUE SHOULD BE INVOKED      
    if(actionCounter == 4) {
        print("invoke segue to next screen")
    }

    loadedCards.removeAtIndex(0)

    if cardsLoadedIndex < allCards.count {
        loadedCards.append(allCards[cardsLoadedIndex])
        cardsLoadedIndex = cardsLoadedIndex + 1
        self.insertSubview(loadedCards[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1], belowSubview: loadedCards[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 2])
    }
}

func swipeRight() -> Void {
    if loadedCards.count <= 0 {
        return
    }
    let dragView: DraggableView = loadedCards[0]
    dragView.overlayView.setMode(GGOverlayViewMode.GGOverlayViewModeRight)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        () -> Void in
        dragView.overlayView.alpha = 1
    })
    dragView.rightClickAction()
}

func swipeLeft() -> Void {
    if loadedCards.count <= 0 {
        return
    }
    let dragView: DraggableView = loadedCards[0]
    dragView.overlayView.setMode(GGOverlayViewMode.GGOverlayViewModeLeft)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        () -> Void in
        dragView.overlayView.alpha = 1
    })
    dragView.leftClickAction()
}

}
```

And the corresponding UIViewController where I load the UIView and where I need to invoke the segue from:

```
class QuestionCardsController: UIViewController {

var moveForwardButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let draggableBackground: DraggableViewBackground = DraggableViewBackground(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.view.addSubview(draggableBackground)

   /*     moveForwardButton = UIButton()
    moveForwardButton.frame =  CGRectMake(160, 240, 35, 10);

    moveForwardButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    moveForwardButton.setTitle("Click here to proceed", forState: .Normal)
    //  moveForwardButton.center = self.center
    moveForwardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DraggableViewBackground.moveToNextScreen), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(moveForwardButton)
 */


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: I think you should move the card logic (`cardsLoadedIndex`, `loadedCards`, `loadCards`, etc.) into the view controller, so the view controller loads all the cards, puts them in the view, and handles them. The methods like `cardSwipedRight` would also be moved, so then when you reach that code, you can simply tell the view controller perform the segue

Comment: Thx, since its a github project (see edit) I hoped to avoid a lot of code changes to achieve that. But let me try it out